# EC2 CentOS 5.0 does not upgrade

Tags: centos, redhat, yum

Recently I grabbed some preconfigured CentOS 5.0 instance from EC2 and installed our stuff on it from rightscale. The instance was a little old, but I assumed that it would be up to date after a single `yum upgrade`.

However, for reasons beyond my understanding, CentOS is not updated beyond 5.0:

```
[root@ip-10-102-63-111:~] yum upgrade
Loading "installonlyn" plugin
Setting up Upgrade Process
Setting up repositories
Reading repository metadata in from local files
No Packages marked for Update/Obsoletion
[root@ip-10-102-63-111:~] cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.0 (Final)
```

The repositories are active and even my EPEL packages are being updated, but it seems that the person who created this instance somehow fixed it at 5.0. However, I really need to update to the latest 5.x. How can I get yum upgrade to work again?

Comment: Can we get the output of "yum repolist?"

Comment: Mad - yes I forgive you :-) And thanks for mentioning this, I was not aware of these courtesies. Actually I assumed that the right answer was decided by voting from all members. Anyway I'll go over my previous posts when I have some time.

Comment: Rilindo - there is no such thing as yum repolist ? Do you mean `yum list` or `yum grouplist` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I solved the problem. Taking a close look at `/etc/yum.repos.d/Centos.list` revealed that the version was hardcoded in the repository url, e.g:

baseurl=http://mirror.rightscale.com/centos/5.0/updates/i386/

So I replaced "5.0" with "5" in every line and then did a `yum clean all` followed by a `yum upgrade` which updated me straight to CentOS 5.7.